# Putting multiple "If not" together

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering if I can do this, it's for a Reddit bot

```
submission = next(x for x in memes_submissions if not x.over_18 if not x.stickied)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: can I do this? Putting multiple `if not` together

Comment: Have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Use `and` or `or` to combine conditions.

```
submission = next(x for x in memes_submissions if not x.over_18 and not x.stickied)
```

Comment: They may mean what do multiple `if`s at the end of a comprehension mean. I didn't know this, but apparently you can list multiple `if`s and they're treated as though they're `and`'d.